# Htaccess redirect RewriteRule not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect url with dresses to `apparel-clothes/dresses`.
For example:

- abc.com/dresses
- abc.com/dresses/casual
- abc.com/dresses/evening-wear
- abc.com/dresses/little-black-dress

Should all be redirected to `abc.com/apparel-clothes/dresses`. I tried to write redirect rule but it does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/dresses/(.*)$ $1/apparel-clothes/dresses/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain name is never part of your `RewriteRule`, so you should not include it (or else, the first capture group you are defining doesn't make sense). It should look more like this:

```
RewriteRule ^dresses/?(.*)$ /apparel-clothes/dresses/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That will rewrite `http://abc.com/dresses` to `http://abc.com/apparel-clothes/dresses/` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You're close but leading slash isn't matched in `.htaccess` in `RewriteRule`.

Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(dresses.*)$ /apparel-clothes/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: I want dresses to replace with apparel-clothes/dresses. Tried the rule but did not work.